# change an excel cell style through C#

Tags: excel, cell

Is it possible to change an excel cell's style through C# if you have the indexes of the cells like:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2,2].Style
```

I don't want all the row to change but only a single cell. The solutions provided before did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, if you want to chane the text color:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2,2].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

You can find all the properties of the cell in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_properties.aspx) (such as `Font`)

Comment: Another problem is that when I set the font whole fonts change in cells. I could not find an accurate answer to my problem in msdn. Could you help figuring this out?

Comment: @bilgestackoverflow: I don't know how you would handle this. You should ask a new question, you are more likely to get answers